# How can I share to a company page using the LinkedIn API (v2)?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to create a WordPress plugin for my our customers that will autoshare the posts to their LinkedIn company page. Do I need Marketing Developer Platform access to actually post to company pages? It would be a bit of a hassle to have every customer go through the application of that product.

The scope rw_company_admin still doesn't give me access to anything company related. It will tell me that I don't have access to visit the company page I am the admin off.

Trying to access the following call:
/v2/organizations/{id}

Gives me this error:
"Not enough permissions to access: GET /organizations/{id}"